# Vuex persistedstate reset logged in user

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is something weird. I want to save vuex store to be persistent on page reload. I use js-cookie and vuex-persistedstate, however, when the page is reloaded the user is half logged in, in my specific case each user has role and depending on that role he has some restriction on the back-end. When a page is reloaded I am still logged in as admin and the state is preserved but I get an error from back-end that I am not an admin.

```js
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: [createPersistedState({ storage: window.sessionStorage 
})],
modules: {
    ...////
  },
});
```

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Hi. How do you handle/validating this roles on back-end? Do you send specific JSON with value from Vuex store from your front-end e.t.c? Or do you add some specific value in the request headers? Please, provide more information in your question. p.s. I have tried your variant and everything is working. Try to clear your session & cookies storage in your browser. It may be some issue with an old cookie invalidation.